# Поддержка разных языков

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Проблема заключается в следующем. Написал приложений одной из функций которого является рекурсивный обход директории. Когда это приложение запускается на другом компьютере с установленным другим языком, оно вылетает с сообщением PROGRAM CRASH. Путем долгого поиска нашел, что проблема заключается в именах файлов и папок содержащих символы китайского языка. Когда программа доходит до них, она вылетает с вышеназванной ошибкой. Как добавить в проект Visual Studio поддержку разных языков? Подскажите пожалуйста. Уже сутки мучаюсь с этим.

```
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW ffd;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t length_of_arg;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    StringCchLength(dir, MAX_PATH, &length_of_arg);


    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, dir);
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    do
    {

        try {
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (!(std::wstring(L".") == std::wstring(ffd.cFileName)) && !(std::wstring(L"..") == std::wstring(ffd.cFileName)))) {
                    try {
                        TCHAR directory[MAX_PATH];
                        StringCchCopy(directory, MAX_PATH, dir);
                        StringCchCat(directory, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\"));
                        StringCchCat(directory, MAX_PATH, ffd.cFileName);
                        //wprintf(L"%s: %s\n", L"Folder", directory);                       
                        get_paths_arguments((STRSAFE_LPWSTR)directory, ctls, len);

                    }
                    catch (exception &ex) {
                        std::cout << "EXCEPTION ON GET DIR NAME";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ffd.cFileName != NULL) {
                    TCHAR directory[MAX_PATH];
                    StringCchCopy(directory, MAX_PATH, dir);
                    StringCchCat(directory, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\"));
                    StringCchCat(directory, MAX_PATH, ffd.cFileName);
                    //wprintf(L"%s: %s\n", L"File", directory);
                    ctls->catls[*len].name = (STRSAFE_LPWSTR)directory;
                    *len = *len + 1;
                    ctls->length = *len;
                    //cout << hFind << endl;
                    if (*len == (ctls->size - 1)) {
                        std::cout << "CRITICAL SIZE OF PATHS STRUCTURE" << std::endl;
                        FindClose(hFind);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (char * str) {
            cout << "EXCEPTION ON GET_PATHS_ARGUMENTS: " << *str << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd));
    FindClose(hFind);
return 0;
```

Comment: Не хватает в вопросе вашего кода, т.к. считаю проблема не в отсутствии поддержки разных языков, как вам показалось

Comment: Исправил. Полностью весь код функции. Там в коде остались мои жалкие попытки поймать исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Проблема была в том, что не проверялось возвращаемое значение функций StringCchCopy и StringCchCat. После того, как получил возвращаемое значение и сравнил его с S_OK, все стало хорошо. Проблема видимо была с превышением максимальной длины пути.